# Why is it that the first user.id only display in the modal?

Tags: php, modal-dialog

Why is it that the first user.id only display in the modal?

Here is my sample code

```
if($_SESSION['type'] == "Client" || $_SESSION['type'] == "Nursemaid")
{
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE type = 'Agency'");
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
?>
<div>
  <a href="#"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></a>
  <a href="#"><?php echo $row['type'] ?></a>
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reqNm">Request nursemaid</button>
</div>
```

This is my modal target

```
<div class="modal" id="reqNm">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $row['user.id']; ?>">
  <input type="checkbox" name="t1" value="gwapa">sample
  <input type="checkbox" name="t2" value="but.an">sample
</div>
<?php
 }?>
```

I don`t understand why it is only the first data can be display in my modal.

But if I dont use modal, it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

That would be because you're only setting the first/last ID to the modal. You'd be better off with a solution similar to this.

1 Set a "data-id" attribute on the "modal" click link as such;

```
<button id="a-custom-button-id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reqNm" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Request nursemaid</button>
```

2 Create a jQuery event on the click of said button

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'button#a-custom-button-id', function() {
    var id = jQuery(this).data('id'); // fetch the ID

    // place the ID as the value for your modal item;
    jQuery('.modal input[name="a"]').val(id);
});
```

That way, when the user clicks the button, it'll populate the input with the relevant ID.

<sup>***Note:*** *This code is untested, you will need to configure it to ensure it works as required.*</sup>